# Python use def() to open and read file and write it in new format into new file

Tags: python, function, url-rewriting

I try to open and change the file. The code works only on first three line then its stack.

My file is:

```
Eskil Johnsson
7901105838
Löberöd 29, 521 29  KÄTTLISTORP
Anna Göransson
7102022980
Klubbvägen 18, 770 65  BY KYRKBY
```

My code:

```py
def main():
    file_content = read_from_file()
    write_to_file(file_content)

def read_from_file():
    with open('C:\\Users\\saran\\OneDrive\\Dokument\\names2.txt', 'r+', encoding = 'utf_8') as f:
        file_content = []
        line = f.readline()
        line = line.split()
        while(len(line) > 0):
            print(line[1] + ' ' + line[0])
            line = f.readline()
            tal = int(line[8])
            if (tal % 2) == 0:
                print('[K]')
            else:
                print('[M]')
            line = f.readline()
            print(line)
        return file_content

main()
```

Comment: code could be simpler if you would use `for line in f:` and `line = next(f)`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reading the lines in the while statement.

Try this:

```
    while(len(line) > 0):
        print(line[1] + ' ' + line[0])
        line = f.readline()
        tal = int(line[8])
        if (tal % 2) == 0:
            print('[K]')
        else:
            print('[M]')
        line = f.readline()
        print(line)
        line = f.readline()
        line = line.split()
```